# android invokeandwait equivalent

Tags: android, multithreading

Is there an equivalent of the method SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait in the Android SDK?

Or can I easily emulate it?

I need to post a treatment from a secondary thread to the UI thread and wait that the UI finish its execution and returns a value to the secondary thread

Answer (score 0):

First, this probably is not a good idea. Users are allowed to press the HOME button, the BACK button, accept phone calls, etc., in which case the UI may not "finish its execution" in any meaningful fashion. You are better served having the background thread terminate once it sends its results to the main application thread, and then the main application thread can fork another thread if and when the user does something with those results.

Beyond that, look at `java.util.concurrent` and find something that meets your needs, such as a `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

Comment: When I say "finish its execution" this means "finish the threatment execution". I can't launch another thread because I need to use local thread variables.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but in case it may help. Create an `AndroidUtilities` class:

```
public class AndroidUtilities {
    public static void runOnUiThreadAndWait(Activity act, final Runnable runnable) {
        synchronized (runnable) {
            act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    runnable.run();
                    synchronized (runnable) {
                        runnable.notify();
                    }
                }
            });
            try {
                runnable.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage in worker thread:

```
AndroidUtilities.runOnUiThreadAndWait(act, new Runnable() {...});
```

Synchronization must be done explicitly: the EDT must execute the UI code and `notify`, while the worker thread must submit the UI code to the EDT and `wait`

Cheers